Why is the system file count different than the number of files uploaded by filezilla
I recently signed Google Drive's 2TB plan to put my backups. Then the process of choosing the best method to upload my files began. After many tries and errors and 3 1/2 days of uploading files (see question Is there any way to upload large amounts of files to Google Drive[...]?), I finally got the files there. But the number of files informed by RClone simply didn´t match.
So, as most files were in the cloud already I used Filezilla Pro with the "skip if different size" option. Skipping most files would be fast enough.
As I made lots of trial and error I need a way to check if all the files where uploaded. But I just can make the numbers match up.
The number of files informed as uploaded by Filezilla is 928,744.
When I sum the result of du -s * for the uploaded dirs I get 1,046,917 a difference of 118,173 files.
So I thought that Filezilla may be excluding dirs from the count. But
find ./des ./bkp ./progs "./Desktop" ./data ./Music ./Documents ./bin ./Images -type d | wc -l
returned only 116,990.
So I think it's not the dirs. If it is there is still a gap. Why ? What's making these numbers not match ? How can I check if all files are really uploaded to Google Drive ?
